# iOS UINavigationController Not Working

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm creating a tour screen where a user would swipe left and right to show some instructional pages.

However I'm having issues in loading pushing the next view. I've created a UINavigationController as below in a handleSwipes method:

```
TourViewController2 *tourView2 = [[TourViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"TourViewController2" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

[navigationController pushViewController:tourView2 animated:YES];
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Aniket Kote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18738171/1009414) wrote, you have to not only create `UINavigationController`, but also make it `rootViewController` in you application. After done this, `UINavigationConroller` became a main container and all others vies are placed inside it. For this reason you should not create `UINavigationController` every time you want to navigate through pages, but only one for all navigation path, eg. when you application in launching. 
Next you can use this "global" navigation controller like

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tourView2 animated:YES];
```

Comment: Hi,So you are saying if the UINavigationController has already been defined in any other class within the app: I just need to use
 TourViewController2 *tourView2 = [[TourViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"TourViewController2" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tourView2 animated:YES];

Comment: @SaeUs, Yes, if current UIViewController is already embedded in navigationController. look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/navigationController .

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:

TourViewController2 *tourView2 = [[TourViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"TourViewController2" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController* navigationController =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tourView2];

 self.window.rootViewController=navigationController;
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. However my class has no window property is this something that can be simply defined?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your requirement, i will not go on your approach. I will suggest the use of  "`Page Control`". As defined by Apple below :-

> UIPageControl indicates the number of open pages in an application by
>   displaying a dot for each open page. The dot that corresponds to the
>   currently viewed page is highlighted. UIPageControl supports
>   navigation by sending the delegate an event when a user taps to the
>   right or to the left of the currently highlighted dot.

Hope this helps you !